# How to merge two queries into a single query in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here I have two query for one table. Second query's $match contain result from first query.

```
db.histories.aggregate([    
    {$match: {
        from: userid,
        connectTime: {"$gte":yesterday},
        status:'completed'
      }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$groupId',
        groupId: { $last: '$groupId' },
        callId:{ $last: '$callId' },
      }},
    { $sort: {
        connectTime:-1
      } }
  ])
```

The result of first query contain "callId",  using that "callId" I'm aggregating second query.

```
db.histories.aggregate([    
    {$match: {
        $or: [{ callId: {"$in": groupCallIdArray} }, { connectedCallId: {"$in": groupCallIdArray} }],
        status:'completed'
      }},
    {$group: {
        _id: {'groupId':'$groupId'},
        from: { $last: '$from' },
        to: { $last: '$to' },
        minimumTime: { $last: '$minimumTime' },
        noOfcalls: {$sum:1},
        duration:{ $sum: '$duration' },
      }}
  ])
```

Do we have any way to merge two queries into a single query.

**Input JSON**

```
[{
 "_id" : ObjectId("60fe4bf5c0fe3d0017059776"),
 "callId" : "CAbfadc16eed3f493f742b208e283848af",
 "connectedCallId" : "CA0c61d90d1694ef219b42412246570c63",
 "from" : ObjectId("6062f39c9ccebd00178bf302"),
 "to" : ObjectId("606d59547db42d00178234a6"),
 "callConnectTime" : 2021-07-26 05:44:19.573Z,
 "status" : "completed",
 "minimumTime" : 15,
 "duration" : 24,
 "groupId" : ObjectId("60c8908e55242c00170e3e00"),
}]
```

**First QUERY OUTPUT**

```
[
  {
    _id:60fe4bf5c0fe3d0017059776,
    gigsId: 60fe4bf5c0fe3d0017059776,
    callSid: 'CAbfadc16eed3f493f742b208e283848af'
  }
]
```

using first queries output I'm creating match query for second query.
groupCallIdArray = ["CAbfadc16eed3f493f742b208e283848af"]

**Second Query Input**

```
[{
    _id:{groupId:ObjectId("60fe4bf5c0fe3d0017059776")},
    from:ObjectId("6062f39c9ccebd00178bf302"),
    to:ObjectId("606d59547db42d00178234a6"),
    minimumTime:15,
    noOfcalls:1,
    duration:24,
}...
]
```

Comment: Yes there are ways to merge into a single query.  It would be helpful if you included examples of your data, and examples of what the query should report back with - i.e., show the expected inputs and outputs.  Both should be valid JSON and parse with an online parsing tool.  Because you are grouping with $last it implies you have more than one record for a condition.  Your example data should include this condition.

Comment: @barrypicker I have included example json

Comment: Your expected results do not match the first query's output.  It is unclear how you want these two queries to interact.

Comment: @barrypicker I have added first query output also. In the first query I'm trying to find last call from the group. First call output contain callID using that CallID, I'm searching second query. There I'm calculating duration and noOfCalls etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$lookup` to pull in the matches.

Something like

```
db.histories.aggregate([    
    {$match: {
        from: userid,
        connectTime: {"$gte":yesterday},
        status:'completed'
      }},
    { $sort: {
        connectTime:-1
      } }
    {$group: {
        _id: '$groupId',
        groupId: { $last: '$groupId' },
        callId:{ $last: '$callId' },
      }},
   {$group: {
       _id: null,
       groupCallIdArray: { $push: '$callId'}
   }},
   {$lookup: {
       from: 'histories',
       let: { groupCallIdArray: '$groupCallIdArray'},
       pipeline: [
         {$match:{
            status:'completed',
            {$expr: {
               $or: [{ callId: {"$in": '$$groupCallIdArray'} }, { 
                     connectedCallId: {"$in": '$$groupCallIdArray'} }]}}
            }
         },
         {$group: {
           _id: {'groupId':'$groupId'},
           from: { $last: '$from' },
           to: { $last: '$to' },
           minimumTime: { $last: '$minimumTime' },
           noOfcalls: {$sum:1},
          duration:{ $sum: '$duration' },
         }}
       ],
      as: 'results'
   }}
  ])
```